# Rails rearrange links and change the resultant order in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have one task. My app will have links of different websites. Their order is defined in database. I want to rearrange then by drag and drop. The resultant order should be reflected in database. I am a rails newbie. Kindly tell me which gems and scripts and how I can use. Kindly give me code reference or example as well.

Comment: ref link: https://github.com/aishek/activerecord-sortable,
http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/ajax-sortable-lists-rails-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any GUI library for drag and drop. Assign a position to each element. Display by order on position. After drag-n-drop, call ajax to a method/function which will swap the positions in database.

Comment: looks interesting,.